# 2 types of textarea values

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

HTML `<textarea/>` element simultaneously contains 2 "value" fields; and only one of which is visible on viewing the html source of the element. (illustrated in the example below).

Can someone explain why this is so and where does the "Type2" value get stored here?

Theory: [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html)

```js
var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
document.body.appendChild(dummy);
dummy.setAttribute('value', "Type1");
dummy.value = "Type2";

console.log("attributeValue is " + dummy.getAttribute('value'));
console.log(".value is " + dummy.value);
```

Comment: Its stored in DOM element's `value` property

Comment: Textareas do not have/need a value attribute. You are still allowed to add it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setAttribute()` call applies a `value` *attribute* to the `textarea` element in the DOM. This is technically incorrect as `textarea` elements do not have a `value` attribute.

You then set the `value` *property* of the element. This is the correct usage, and is what sets the visible text within the element.

The result of this logic is this HTML:

```
<textarea value="Type1">Type2</textarea>
```

When you use `getAttribute()` you read the (non-standard) `value` *attribute* from the element which returns `Type1`.

When you read the `value` *property* you are (correctly) reading the value contained within the user editable content of the field, which returns `Type2`.

In short, the confusion you have is because you're using an *attribute* named `value` and *property* named `value`, and they are not the same thing when applied to a `textarea`.